# how to set time out for jquery hover function

Tags: jquery, timeout, hover

for example look at these codes please :

HTML:

```
<div id="hvr">hover me</div>
<div id="box" style="background:#ddd; width:100px; height:50px;"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$("#hvr").hover(function(){

    $("#box").animate({width:'150px'},500);
    more animations/functions here ...

}, function(){

    $("#box").animate({width:'100px'},500);
    more animations/functions here ...
});
```

when I hover on the text 3 times quickly, the box animates 3 times after each one is finished.
how can I set a time out for the hover which will disable hover effect until the first animations/functions [ due to the first hover ] are finished ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $("#hvr").hover(function(){    
      $("#box").stop().animate({width:'150px'},500);   
  }, function(){    
      $("#box").stop().animate({width:'100px'},500);
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked: "how can I set a time out for the hover which will disable hover effect until the first animation is finished".

Comment: actually it works, but only for one level animations.
If I add for examples 2 more lines of animations, it won't work.
I want a hover timeout to be set for all inner functions ..